# Deleted logs folder but TensorBoard still showing all the deleted runs

Tags: tensorboard

I'm not sure what's going on but I'm running TensorBoard remotely using an extension in VS Code, and up until recently it was working great. A couple days ago it stopped displaying the metrics for new experiments/training sessions. I thought if I deleted the folder containing the log data it would somehow "reset" TB. No such luck, and it is still showing me all the same old log data that I deleted. I'm not sure how this is possible. Does TB have some kind of cache that I also need to delete?